# Can anyone explain how to wire a CBB61 capacitor to a UK power supply?

Tags: electrical, wiring, capacitor

I have a single phase electric motor which connects to the 240v mains power supply through a CB661 2 connection capacitor (pictured below). The plug has the usual blue, brown, and yellow/green wires, as does the motor, but the motor also has a white wire. Somehow the capacitor connects the plug to the motor, but I am baffled as to how the connections work! Can anyone explain?

[image: Capacitor]
[image: Wire from capacitor to motor]
[image: Capacitor as it was found after accident]

Comment: Does the motor come with a wiring diagram? I *think* the capacitor connects between the phase wire and the motor's extra wire, but don't wire it up and don't quote me on that, until someone is actually sure.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It was in a black box, and I only found out that the box contained a capacitor when it got pulled off.

Comment: So you accidentally disconnected the capacitor and you want to fix it?

Comment: Yes. Neither the nor the capacitor were damaged in my mishap

Comment: I think the answer is easy to guess, but impossible for a knowledgeable person to be confident in without also seeing the motor and its wiring. Preferably you would also take a picture of the plug, but I think it's not strictly necessary because the plug follows the standard colour code.

Comment: I just added a photo of the motor's wiring

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148468/discussion-between-james-hamilton-and-user253751).

Comment: There's more to this story than meets the eye. Why do you have a piece of 4-wire cable not connected to anything? Where did it come from? What's at the other end? How is the switch wired? Can you not easily identify where this capacitor was knocked from, either by eye or by testing for an open circuit on a multi-meter?

Comment: The 4 wire cable is connected to the motor. It was connected to the capacitor. I've uploaded another image of how it was after the capacitor was pulled off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, nobody else has answered, so I'm going to risk it. I'm not an electrician and not confident in this answer, but it seems too obvious to ignore. You should probably wait for an actual electrician can chime in with their opinion in the comments or write their own answer.

I'm 90% sure that brown goes to brown (live), blue goes to blue (neutral), and yellow/green goes to yellow/green (earth). Otherwise, they wouldn't colour-code them that way.

The capacitor branches off the brown wire, which is the live wire, and after the capacitor, the electricity goes to the white wire. (The purpose of this is to create a delayed phase which helps the motor know which way to turn. Explaining it properly is out of scope here.)

It doesn't matter which way around the red and black go. We know the capacitor is a type that works both ways around, or it wouldn't have been in this AC circuit.

I couldn't tell you how to actually make the connections. I assume the white things are wire nuts and you know how to use them.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.

I can work out the wire nuts myself. The key question is what happens to the live wire coming from the plug. Does it go into the same wire nut as either the white or the brown wire coming from the motor, or do I have to do something more complicated?

Comment: @JamesHamilton It connects to both the brown wire coming from the motor, and one wire from the capacitor, at the same time - in the same wire nut - *I think*. (I have to repeat the disclaimer every time I say something, because if I'm wrong and you connect it this way and it blows up or burns your house down, I warned you)

Comment: disclaimer noted! ChatGPT said something similar as a matter of fact. Don't worry, it'll be switched back on outside and I'll hide behind the tractor.

Comment: @JamesHamilton Were it my problem, I'd just wire it up as I described and stand a bit back just in case, but I wouldn't be very worried. I have made many successful projects without being completely sure what I was doing. Giving the advice to *other people* is what makes it a liability, especially when mains electricity is involved (as opposed to a battery).